# How to pass a function as parameter to Callable in Java

Tags: java, callable

I have a function that makes some service call to a database which I do not want to change. But if there are multiple requests that need to run this function, I want to run them in a threadpool. So, I am trying to figure out how to wrap this function in a Callable class. Here is the signature of the function :

```
void invokeCommand(string table, int ctype)
```

The function invokeCommand does not return any value but can throw an exception. I suppose using the following construct is not an option since I have no way of passing parameters and the invokeCommand function to this.

```
Callable<Void> myCommand = new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I learned that another way of doing it would be to define a named class instead of anonymous class and pass the parameters (string, int) through constructor. Is there a way I can also pass the function invokeCommand? What would be the recommended way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Callable<T> is an interface. You cannot do the code above unless you have an impelementation.

Comment: @ha9u63ar you might want to learn about anonymous classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anonymous classes can access `final` variables declared outside them. They can also access member variables of the enclosing class.

```
final String table = ...;
final int ctype = ...;
Callable<Void> myCommand = new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() {
        invokeCommand(table, ctype);
        return null;
    }
};
```

In Java 8, this restriction was loosened - the variable is not required to be declared `final`, but it must be *effectively final*. A variable is effectively final if it is never assigned after its declaration.